# Elements only appear after I input something

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios

For some reason, everything is being initialized properly when I load the page for the first time, except for the paymentID and Amount, which are being display only after I click on something or input anything in a text box.

This is my code which initializes my webpage.

```
created: function () {
    // Initializing persons
    AXIOS.get('/persons')
    .then(response => {
      this.persons = response.data;
      this.persons.forEach(person => this.getRegistrations(person.name))

      this.persons.forEach(person => 
        person.eventsAttended.forEach(event => {
          this.getPaymentofRegistrations(person.name, event.name)
        }))
    })
    .catch(e => {this.errorPerson = e});
.
.
.
.
```

```
getRegistrations: function (personName) {
      AXIOS.get('/events/person/'.concat(personName))
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.data || response.data.length <= 0) return;



        let indexPart = this.persons.map(x => x.name).indexOf(personName);
        this.persons[indexPart].eventsAttended = [];
        response.data.forEach(event => {
          this.persons[indexPart].eventsAttended.push(event);
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        e = e.response.data.message ? e.response.data.message : e;
        console.log(e);
      });
    },

    getPaymentofRegistrations: function (personName, eventName) {
      AXIOS.get('/registrations?person='+personName+'&event='+eventName)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.data || response.data.length <= 0) return;
        let indexPart1 = this.persons.map(x => x.name).indexOf(personName);
        let indexPart2 = this.persons[indexPart1].eventsAttended.map(x => x.name).indexOf(eventName);
        this.persons[indexPart1].eventsAttended[indexPart2].paymentId = response.data.bitcoin.userID;
        this.persons[indexPart1].eventsAttended[indexPart2].paymentAmount = response.data.bitcoin.amount;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
    }
```

Images attached for a better understanding of the problem.[image: Before inputting]

It only takes writing a letter in a text box (without even clicking on a reactive button) for the Payment and Amount info to appear:

[image: After input]

Answer (score 0):

This code is very complex and hard to understand but if I should make a bid `Vue.set` can help for you:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

or you can store `eventsAttended` collections in another data property, not as a nested object.